# How to find location of a file in a maven project

Tags: java, file, io

I am trying to marshal one java object and keep it inside my project. For that I was giving relative path. I am trying this in a maven project. Now whenever I am running the program it is giving **FileNotFoundException**. Here few people suggested to use-

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")

or

File file = new File("./");
file.getAbsolutePath();

or

getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString()

or

getClass().getResource("fileName").getPath() // printing null
```

but none of the above are working cause my eclipse workspace and local github repository both are different and that is why the above code is always pointing to eclipse.

Please suggest me what to do and how can I save my marshaled object to one of my project package.

Comment: What is your workspace path? And what is the path of your file?

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj
**workspace path:** D:/EclipseWorkspace
**file path:** D:/GIT/<projectName>/src/main/java/com/practice/marshal/Messages.java

My main concern is to create a new file and store it in this **(D:/GIT/<projectName>/src/main/java/com/practice/marshal/)** place but I am not able to find the location dynamically.

Comment: You should not store such files under src folder. The file you are generating should be under classes/com/practice/marshal folder. Can you check?

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj This did not work because I want to store inside D:/GIT folder but the above code is returning me D:/EclipseWorkspace folder which is wrong